# Tiling bitmaps on a wxFrame

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, wxperl

I want to set the background on a frame with tiling bitmaps, using wxPerl.
With the help of an example from [wxWidgets](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/html/htmlwin.cpp) I've come up with the code below.
Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything, the frame remains blank.
Is this even the right way to do it, or is there another way?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package MyFrame;
use Wx qw(:everything);
use base qw( Wx::Frame );

sub new {
    my ( $class, $path ) = @_;
    my $self
        = $class->SUPER::new( undef, -1, 'Test', [ -1, -1 ], [ 600, 400 ], );
    $self->set_tiling_background($path);
    return $self;
}

sub set_tiling_background {
    my ( $self, $path ) = @_;

    ## Create a wxBitmap from the file
    my $file = IO::File->new($path);
    binmode $file;

    my $handler = Wx::BMPHandler->new();
    my $image   = Wx::Image->new();
    $handler->LoadFile( $image, $file );
    my $bitmap = Wx::Bitmap->new($image);

    ## Just to check that the bitmap is good.
    $bitmap->SaveFile('saved.bmp', wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP);

    ## Draw the bitmap tiling over the frame
    ## https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/html/htmlwin.cpp
    my $dc = Wx::WindowDC->new($self);

    my $size_x = $bitmap->GetWidth;
    my $size_y = $bitmap->GetHeight;

    for ( my $x = 0; $x < 600; $x += $size_x ) {
        for ( my $y = 0; $y < 400; $y += $size_y ) {
            $dc->DrawBitmap( $bitmap, $x, $y, 0 );
        }
    }
}

package MyApp;
use base 'Wx::App';
my $path = '/path/to/bitmap.bmp';

sub OnInit {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $frame = MyFrame->new($path);
    $frame->Show(1);
}

package main;
MyApp->new->MainLoop;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the `ERASE_BACKGROUND` event handler:

```
package MyFrame;
use Wx qw(:everything wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
use base qw( Wx::Frame );
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Wx::Event;

sub new {
    my ( $class, $path ) = @_;
    my $self
        = $class->SUPER::new( undef, -1, 'Test', [ -1, -1 ], [ 600, 400 ], );
    my $bitmap = Wx::Bitmap->new( $path , wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG );
    Wx::Event::EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND( $self, sub { $self->setBgImage( $bitmap, @_) });
    return $self;
}

sub setBgImage {
    my ( $self, $bitmap, $frame, $evt ) = @_;

    return if !defined $evt;
    my $dc = $evt->GetDC();
    my $size_x = $bitmap->GetWidth;
    my $size_y = $bitmap->GetHeight;

    for ( my $x = 0; $x < 600; $x += $size_x ) {
        for ( my $y = 0; $y < 400; $y += $size_y ) {
            $dc->DrawBitmap( $bitmap, $x, $y, 0 );
        }
    }
}

package MyApp;
use base 'Wx::App';
my $path = 'logo.jpg';

sub OnInit {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $frame = MyFrame->new($path);
    $frame->Show(1);
}

package main;
MyApp->new->MainLoop;
```

This gives me the following output on Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]

See also: [wxPython: Putting a Background Image on a Panel](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer already explains how to do this correctly, but I'd also like to explain what did you do wrong originally: you can't paint on `WindowDC` just once and hope to accomplish anything. Any persistent drawing must be done on `PaintDC` in `EVT_PAINT` handler or, as a special kind of exception, on the DC provided to `EVT_BACKGROUND_ERASE` handler. If you set up `EVT_PAINT` handler calling your original `set_tiling_background` and using `PaintDC` from it, it would have worked too.

In fact, on modern platforms (GTK3, macOS), you can't use neither `WindowDC` nor `ClientDC` at all, drawing on them simply doesn't work.